# Is there an existing way to find out if there is an association between two words in a sentence using NLP

Tags: python, nlp

So, I was working on word2vec , playing with it and although it's a great tool for finding similarities between two words,But when we come to finding a semantic association between two words it cannot be used. It would be interesting to know if there's an existing way, if yes how accurate is it and what principles does it work on?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean? It is unclear to me if you are talking about something like dependency parsing or coreference resolution etc.

Comment: Example:  " I am using ibuprofen ( a drug) . I use it for headaches. I get chills,stomach ache from it.".  Here I want to find the association of the drug(ibuprofen) and disease (headaches) and drug and side effects (chills, stomach ache)

Comment: Then I would do a mix of two things. First, coreference resolution. That's the task that links "it" with Ibuprophen. Then, relation extraction where you can extract that there is a relation such as "drug causes symptom"